# How to trace source of IE8 Security Warning?

Tags: security, internet-explorer, https

I am getting the dreaded security warning when running my GWT web app under IE8:
"this webpage contains content that will not be delivered using a secure HTTPS"

It of course works fine with Firefox and Chrome.

I have taken a look at the requests with firebug and I see no HTTP requests.

I have also used both Fiddler and HttpWatch with IE and I still see no HTTP requests.

Can anyone provide me with some clues as to what else might trigger this warning?

Comment: Are you using protocol independent URIs (`href="//path/to/stylesheet.css`) for your stylesheets? Internet Explorer downloads those twice when you're on https, once using https and once using http.

Comment: Looking at the stylesheet links in the IE dev tools shows they are explicit for the mode. e.g href="https://..."

Comment: If you are using PIE.htc, you might want to look at ["Secure and nonsecure" Warning](http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=128)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are certain snippets of Javascript that can also cause a problem. Please see:

http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/09/17/even-more-problems-with-the-ie-8-mixed-content-warning/

Also, have a look through the pile of comments on:

http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/04/23/fixing-the-ie-8-warning-do-you-want-to-view-only-the-webpage-content-that-was-delivered-securely/

Some of the commenters have found and fixed other causes of the warning too.

Comment: Thanks, looks like my problem is this one: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925014