# IE: Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely? alert suddenly

Tags: security, ssl, internet-explorer-8, https

Suddenly one website I'm creating started to show this message on IE while using https pages...

> Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely?

the weird thing is that it wasn't showing this before, so what could end up going wrong?

somebody could help me on that? what are the procedures to end with this message?

I'm calling all the external js with `src="/javascripts/main.js"` for example so it should follow the protocol being used currently.

Comment: You're doing a non https request somewhere around, probably an image, look for it.

Comment: thanks @Ben this is weird because I've looked for it and nothing at all, just added the website link to the question. the only requests using http are links for other websites, like footer etc.

Comment: Did you fix it? it doesn't throw me any warnings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trace source of IE8 Security Warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201042/how-to-trace-source-of-ie8-security-warning)

Comment: @Ben, yes I think it's fixed now...as @jeffmaphone pointed on this question says that some snippets of javascript provoke this warning.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34094617/2404470) maybe useful for end users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a bug on one of the javasrcripts was making the alert popup, which is completely crazy...because this has nothing to do with security requests.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to turn this off, but as everything you with security you must weight the risks.

1. Navigate to Tools-> Internet Options-> Security
2. Select the "Security Tab"
3. Click the "Custom Level" button at the bottom
4. In the "Miscellaneous" section change "Display mixed content" to Enable
5. Then click the "OK" button

Fissh